My bash script not working, used the command mv
Below is the script created to move files from one location to another.
#!/bin/bash
mv -f /home/ftpuser/*.txt  /usr/local/********/Source/
# I tried the above script and in the crontab it is showing that it had executed, but at actual file did not move from one location to another location.
# Crontab
*/5 * * * * root /user/local/********/encrypt.sh
*/3 * * * * root /home/ec2-user/Desktop/MoveCommand.sh

i) encrypt.sh
xport PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mask_directory/jdk1.8.0_221/jre
set JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/mask_directoryjdk1.8.0_221/jre"
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
java -classpath "/usr/local/mask_directory/bcpg-jdk16-1.46.jar:/usr/local/mask_directory/lib/bcpro$
Home Directory move bash script
#!/bin/bash
mv -f /home/ftpuser/*.txt  /usr/local/mask_directory/Source/
ii) Mask_Directory
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root    root     424 Dec  2 11:26 encrypt.sh
MoveCommand.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user       75 Dec 24 13:55 MoveCommand.sh
iii) clarification of Directory
The package is located in usr directory to encrypt the files, which I can not change the path.
iv) bin/sh: /home/ec2-user/Desktop/MoveCommand.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

it's  crontab, not cronetab

Standard cron job troubleshooting: have it collect output and errors by adding >>/tmp/MoveCommand.log 2>&1 to the end of the crontab entry, let it run, then check that file to see if it indicates what's happening as the job runs. Also, see "Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?"

Can you confirm that ******** is a placeholder for some fixed text?  The question would be much improved by editing it to replace ******** with foo/bar.  My initial reading was that "all those wildcards are going to cause problems".

*** is the mask directory which I can not comment publicly,

What is "the crontab", and what is the exact log message that leads you to believe it executed? You appear to have used the format for the system-wide /etc/crontab (with the additional user field) which is inappropriate if you used the regular user crontab (via crontab -e for example).

[Edit] your question and show output of ls -l /home/ec2-user/Desktop/MoveCommand.sh. Remove following line if it has nothing to do with the question: */5 * * * * root /user/local/********/encrypt.sh

Whose cronjobs do we see up there? The one from user root or from your personal user?

-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 75 Dec 24 13:55 /home/ec2-user/Desktop/MoveCommand.sh
Below Command used to see the crontab live monitoring
tail -f /var/log/cron

Have you used crontab -e to edit your crontab?

Yes..crontab -e to edit crontab

Wrong syntax. Remove " root " from your crontab.

now the command looks like this "*/5 * * * * /user/local/maks_directory/encrypt.sh
*/3 * * * * /home/ec2-user/Desktop/MoveCommand.sh"

Please EDIT your question (don't answer in the comments, edit the question) and show us the current situation. Make sure to include i) the contents of /user/local/maks_directory/encrypt.sh and /home/ec2-user/Desktop/MoveCommand.sh, ii) the output of ls -l on each of those two files. iii) Clarify if you actually mean /usr/ or /user since you mention both. iv) change the cron line to be * * * * * /home/ec2-user/Desktop/MoveCommand.sh 2>/tmp/my.cron.log wait for a minute so it runs, then run cat /tmp/my.cron.log and show us the output of that.
